# How is AMRI calculated and what does it mean in terms of link prediction in knowledge graph?

Tags: entity, operations-research, knowledge-graph, entity-linking

I am reading a paper on link prediction titled "The Open Challenge for Inductive Link Prediction in Knowledge Graphs". The authors introduced the "AMRI" metric. I don't know how to calculate the AMRI metric. Who can help me and write an example for that?

Comment: If the authors introduced the AMRI metric it is perhaps best to ask them how to calculate it.

Comment: I emailed and asked the authors the question. But so far I have not received any answer. thanks for your attention.